# How to populate Pivot Table in MySQL with Date dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, dynamic, mariadb, pivot

I have a table in which information about **employee attendance**.

This is how the table looks like:

| att_id | scan_date | scan_in_time | scan_out_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-21 | 2023-10-21 08:10:00 | 2023-10-21 16:20:00 |
| 2 | 2023-10-21 | 2023-10-21 07:36:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2023-10-21 | 2023-10-21 07:15:00 | 2023-10-21 16:43:00 |
| 1 | 2023-10-22 | 2023-10-22 08:25:50 | 2023-10-22 16:23:10 |

Is it possible to get output like below?

| att_id | 2023-10-21 | 2023-10-22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:10:00 - 16:20:00 | 08:25:50 - 16:23:10 |
| 2 | 07:36:00 - NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 07:15:00 - 16:43:00 | NULL |

i'm using MariaDB 10.4 in production environments. thanks in advance!

Comment: send me your email. I have the sql statement for your table buffen@t-online.de

Comment: HERE is quer Answer: use Prepared Statement like this:

SELECT  CONCAT( "SELECT att_id, ",GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("max(if(scan_date = '", c.scan_date,"',CONCAT(COALESCE(TIME(scan_in_time),'NULL'),' - ',COALESCE(TIME(scan_out_time),'NULL')),null)) AS '", c.scan_date,"'" ) )," FROM ea GROUP BY att_id ORDER BY att_id") into @myq
 FROM
 ( SELECT DISTINCT scan_date
  FROM ea 
 ORDER BY scan_date
) as c;


-- only for Testing
SELECT @myq;

PREPARE stmt FROM @myq;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Comment: Note [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(...)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) is a single statement version for MariaDB, since its not MySQL.

Comment: @BerndBuffen. thank you so much! your query was run as well